# Intent-Filter won't properly respond to content

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm having trouble getting my application to respond to the `content` filter scheme.

I have an `intent-filter`

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.riley"
                android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
```

However, that will not open the a .riley file from my gmail. If I remove the scheme, like so:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.riley" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This will now open the file from my gmail. I figured that it must not be from the `content` scheme, then. So I logged my intent like so:

```
System.out.println("Intent\nScheme: " + intent.getScheme() + "\nAction: " + intent.getAction() + "\nFlags: " + intent.getFlags() + "\nPackage: " + intent.getPackage() + "\nMIME: " + intent.getType() + "\nData: " + intent.getData());
System.out.println("Intent\nScheme: " + intentUri.getScheme() + "\nPath: " + intentUri.getPath() + "\nHost: " + intentUri.getHost() + "\nTo String: " + intentUri.toString());
```

And my logs come out like this:

```
03-26 11:17:44.123: I/System.out(8796): Intent
03-26 11:17:44.123: I/System.out(8796): Scheme: content
03-26 11:17:44.123: I/System.out(8796): Action: android.intent.action.VIEW
03-26 11:17:44.123: I/System.out(8796): Flags: 50855937
03-26 11:17:44.123: I/System.out(8796): Package: null
03-26 11:17:44.123: I/System.out(8796): MIME: application/vnd.riley
03-26 11:17:44.123: I/System.out(8796): Data: content://gmail-ls/emailaddress@gmail.com/messages/5277/attachments/0.1.7/BEST/false
03-26 11:17:44.133: I/System.out(8796): Intent
03-26 11:17:44.133: I/System.out(8796): Scheme: content
03-26 11:17:44.133: I/System.out(8796): Path: /emailaddress@gmail.com/messages/5277/attachments/0.1.7/BEST/false
03-26 11:17:44.133: I/System.out(8796): Host: gmail-ls
03-26 11:17:44.133: I/System.out(8796): To String: content://gmail-ls/emailaddress@gmail.com/messages/5277/attachments/0.1.7/BEST/false
```

This is quite confusing for me, as the path does not actually end in ".riley", but if I set the MIME-type to check for ".riley", the `intent-filter` stops working.

**What should my `intent-filter` be in order to open this properly and why doesn't my first example work?**